# I am completely new to git and I am unable to remove dist.tar from the files

Tags: html, git, github

Everything started when I started seeing .DS_Store populating  every time I neeeded to performing a git push for my github account.

I created a file named  dist.tar in my folder and I am having trouble because when I do ls it now populates.

Now every time I do a git status I get a message

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
dist.tar

I am trying to delete this dist.tar file, so I can get my code working with the git push and uploaded my index.htlm on  github.com in my repository files.

I am very confused and don't know how to delete that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **dist.tar** to your **.gitignore** file.
So your **.gitignore** file will have something like this:

```
#ignore dist.tar
dist.tar
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am very new... so right now I perform the cd file and then ls which i get  these three files :   _config.yml dist.tar index.md     site

Answer (score 0):

To delete the file from the local folder. Execute command `rm dist.tar` in your terminal.

To remove the file from git tracking, create a file named .gitignore and add dist.tar to the .gitignore file

```
#ignore unneeded files
dist.tar
```